# Is there a name for "leak" of CPU usage?

Tags: naming

A counterpart to memory leak, but involving CPU time instead - the program's CPU usage slowly climbing to 100% and then the whole system slowing down - without memory footprint changing.

An example where this could happen - a program aggregating old data, polling the queue for samples in given interval; while the database purges obsolete data, the program checks for data since the beginning of operation, picking increasingly growing number of "no record" as the purged period grows.

Or a program, where the complexity of calculation grows as O(exp(n)), while n is proportional to the data set size; the data set grows normally, never exceeding foreseen, allocated space, but the algorithm processing speed grinds to a halt.

Is there an official name for this kind of problem/bug?

Comment: No, I would speak of useless computation, or waste of CPU time.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Still, that waste may be constant, a problem of optimality but not one that makes for a critical bug, one that makes the program useless in the long run. Imagine you have to quit and restart the app every hour or two to keep it running.

Comment: I'm seeing three close votes for "primarily OPINION based" on a question that asks for an OFFICIAL name for given effect. WTF?? Do you all really think calling the situation where a program repeatedly doesn't deallocate memory where it should, "Memory Leak" is also an opinion-based issue?

Comment: I don't think you'll find an open question here that asks if there's a name for allocating memory and not freeing it.

Comment: [Scalability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability) is a problem for many algorithms once the data set becomes sufficiently large.  An [infinite loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop) can consume 100% of a single cpu core.  When an applications working set greatly exceeds physical memory, you get virtual memory [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)) which can resemble little to no progress, though usually due to being IO bound rather than CPU bound.  Thrashing can also be a problem with CPU caches alone.

Comment: @Erik: at this very moment my Firefox session consumes 40% of memory out of about 60% used by the whole system (and remaining 40% being free). Meanwhile, CPU load (caused by Firefox) oscillates around 200%, and switching a tab takes some 6 seconds. Despite none of the tabs having anything computationally intensive - one paused Youtube movie, a bunch of pictures, some sites that do maybe one AJAX connection per minute. I just wanted to know how if there's a name for this situation.

Comment: (also, if I saved current session, quit Firefox, started it again, restoring the session, the CPU usage after initial surge would go to something like 20%... then continue to climb over several next days)

Comment: I think it is a reasonable question, and commented merely to add some food for thought.  If I had a real answer I'd give it to you, and I think the condition perhaps deserves a simple name!

Comment: I think the question is valid and the name for this problem is coding error. Whatever computational tasks might be launched, the application needs to manage. If a large operation is aborted, the calculation should be terminated. This is why any modern language will have concurrency classes that offer the ability to properly manage threads. It also could come about because of scalability problems. With clod services and such, apps can and should be built to scale out as needed to handle peak compute workloads. But again, the app should still manage those workloads and scale down accordingly.

Comment: One possible cause would be a *callback leak* : when an operation takes longer and longer, it can be because the data being processed becomes more complex and takes more time (but that isn't happening here because memory usage is constant), or because more and more logic is being added to the handler.  If the data complexity IS growing, but computation is growing more quickly, that's *poor scalability* as Erik already commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an official name for this kind of problem/bug?

No there isn't.  (This is a fact, not an opinion.)

There isn't an unofficial one either.

Comment: CPU Load Problems. Thats the name.

Comment: Or "a bug".  But neither of these captures the specific characteristic in the way that "memory leak" does.  Hence my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A system taking an inordinate time to compute something is usually just presumed to *hang* or *be hung*. The idea is that a computation that takes exponential time quickly becomes so slow that you can't distinguish it from an actual infinite loop, e.g. a total hang.